# Categorize multiple items in Outlook Smart Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, email-filter

I'm using Microsoft Outlook for Mac (2016, Office 365 Subscription) and have created a [Smart Folder for my Uncategorized Mail](https://superuser.com/questions/598107/ms-outlook-search-folder-for-uncategorized-mail/598108). I did this because I wanted to find mails I have not yet sorted and put them into categories. I can select a single mail and then use the context menu or the [categorize button](https://davidhcma.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/categorize-button.png) to sort it, and it will disappear from my smart folder (which is what I want). However, when I cmd-click multiple mails, both the button and the context menu option get greyed out, meaning to sort the mails from this folder I have to do so one at a time (I can categorize multiple mails at once without a problem in other folders, say Inbox or Archive). Is there some way to enable categorization of multiple mails at once in a Smart Folder? Outlook Help didn't and a Google search was unfruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my [question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac/categorize-multiple-items-in-outlook-smart-folder/5fa2cdb5-a74c-4119-82db-ca85e1741f82) on Microsoft Community and got the classic "it's not a bug, it's a feature" response.

It turns out that if a search or Smart Folder has "All Mail" as its scope, mass categorization will not work. However, if the scope is "Current Folder" or "Subfolders" then it will work. My workaround for this issue was to remake my Smart Folder to search the Archive, where most of my mails live.

It would still be great to be able to mass-categorize while searching all mails. Seems like [someone else wanted this feature](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/15296928-support-for-mass-categorizing-search-results-i-ca) too, so I upvoted it on Outlook Feedback.